# Is this permutation secure?

Tags: cryptanalysis, chosen-plaintext-attack, permutation, differential-analysis, linear-cryptanalysis

Let vector ${\bf d} \in \{ \pm 1 \}^n$ be the message we want to send. In my system, ${\bf d}$ is multiplied by an $n \times n$ [Fourier matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) ${\bf F}$, as follows

$$ {\bf x} = {\bf F} {\bf d}  $$

where

$$ {\bf F} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  1 & e^{jw} & e^{j2w}&\cdots & e^{j(n-1)w} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  1 & e^{j(n-1)w} &e^{j2(n-1)w}& \cdots & e^{j(n-1)(n-1)w} 
 \end{pmatrix}$$
We perform secret permutation $P$ for ${\bf x}$ provided that only the legitimate parties know the permutation and $P$ changes for every transmission.

1. Does multiplying by ${\bf F}$ help to diffuse?
2. Is this actually breakable?
3. If so, what kind of cryptanalysis can be used?

Comment: What does "We perform secret permutation $P$" mean? Do we multiply by a permutation matrix?

Comment: It is only interleaving of $ X $, assume adversary does not know $ P $

Comment: So, mathematically speaking, the interleaving is done via $\bf P x$, where $\bf P$ is a permutation matrix, right?

Comment: P is randomly generated  interleaving $ N $ indices from some seed. If the transmitted cipher is $C$, $ C(i) =X(P(i)), i=[1,.., N] $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying by $F$ cannot help. It is publicly known, and easily invertible. Therefore an adversary can easily undo it, leaving them with simply the permuted inputs $\mathbf{Px}$.

Moreover, permuting the input cannot be IND-CPA secure. This is because permutation matrices leave norms invariant, meaning:

$$\lVert \mathbf{Px}\rVert_p = \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_p$$
For any $p$-norm (including the "$\ell_0$-norm", meaning the Hamming weight). This means that frequency analysis can be used to attack enciphering via solely permuting the input. In general these ciphers are known as [transposition ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher).

Comment: Thanks @Mark, i appreciate if you are aware of a good paper or reference how frequency analysis is used to reveal the random permutation as you mentioned.

Comment: @Riva11 [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15748/frequency-analysis-of-transposition-ciphers) contains some information. The basic idea is that if you know the plaintext is formatted a certain way (say "Is correctly spelled english text"), you can use this to mount an attack. The character which occurs most often in the ciphertext is very likely to be one of the most common occurring characters in english text. You can repeat this with "pairs of consecutive characters" or "triplets of consecutive characters" (known as bigrams and trigrams).

Comment: There's of course still work to be done after having that technical insight, but the work is rather "elementary" --- a professor I had in undergrad would assign it (with suitable "guidance" in how to break it down into individual parts) as a programming project in an intro to python course.

Comment: it does seem some works has been done in context of random and pseudorandom permutation that can be secure so it might be not simply as that

Comment: Regardless of how you generate your permutations, $\mathbf{Px}$ will leak the number of 0's which occur in $\mathbf{x}$. This means that it cannot hope to be IND-CPA. Using the standard left/right notion of indistinguishability, submit $\mathbf{x}_0 = 0^n$ and $\mathbf{x}_1 = 1^n$. Then an adversary can easily determine $0/1$ from $\mathbf{Px}_b$ by simply counting the number of 0's in the ciphertext.

Comment: So by the best observable behavior is the number of ones and zeros. But $X$ is non-binary values, some discrete values. I read this paper https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/FastPRP%3A-Fast-Pseudo-Random-Permutations-for-Small-Stefanov-Shi/7639a9d8bc9cc29d3dcf9e66e582bdb4802e193b,  do you have suggestions to improve the security of the system mentioned above?

Comment: @Riva11 I bring up that (simple) attack because IND-CPA security is considered the weakest acceptable level of security in cryptography, and your construction trivially does not meet it. Also pseudo-random permutations are not bad, but you have to apply them with some nuance. For example, if you have a function which on input some small value $k$ (you could view this as a PRG seed) outputs a permutation $\mathbf{P}_k$, one can use this function (which is known as a "block cipher") in a number of different ways (known as "modes of operation") to form secure encryption schemes.

Comment: But the way that you suggest is not a secure method, and can have devestating results. For example, say that you break your data $\textbf{x} = \textbf{x}_1,\dots,\textbf{x}_\ell$ into fixed-length blocks (pseudo-random permutations are fixed length in practice), and "encrypt" by computing $\mathbf{P}\textbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf{P}\textbf{x}_\ell$ where $\mathbf{P}$ is the PRP corresponding to your shared key $k$. This is precisely "Electric Codebook Mode" of encryption (see [this encryption of the linux penguin](https://tonybox.net/posts/ecb-penguin/), which does a poor job encrypting the data).

Answer (score 3):

This is problematic as stated. You need to specify a probability distribution for that complex matrix, but the complex field is infinite. This then implies that you need to also carefully define some detection/quantization mechanism.

So, why complex numbers?

Comment: Addition: it is at least possible to make the system secure. Make F all-zero, except in the diagonal, making that random in $\{-1,1\}$. Then the system become equivalent to a One Time Pad, provided that _"$P$ changes for every transmission"_ (understood as: for each message $d$).

Comment: @fgrieu, of course, I was trying to understand why this strange setup.

Comment: Thanks, the main secrecy method is the permutation. However, i was wondering is the matrix induces vulnerablity or diffusion. It is part of the insecure system. It's values are fixed for a given size and the complex elements can be considered as constants values. So the matrix elements does not change. For clarification, it's IFFT of the information, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix. I wanted to know if the linear relationship can reveal some plaintext deduced from the permutation.

Comment: please rewrite the question mathematically, on the basis of the comments above. "it's IFFT of the information" doesn't parse for me. The question should be self-contained.

Comment: ok @kodlu i edited the question